# How to add two dataframes with different dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Python, which needs to be added, but want the output as the last table not the one that's an outcome of performing `df1+df2`.

df1:

```
index   6   12  24
2010    2   3   4
2011    2   3   4
2012    2   3   4
```

df2:

```
index   6   12
2011    2   3   
2012    2   3
```

df1+df2:

```
index   6   12  
2011    4   6   
2012    4   6
```

Required Output:

```
index   6   12  24   
2010    2   3   4    
2011    4   6   4    
2012    4   6   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. this works !!